# Combining two tokens-dataframe with unequal number of rows into a list

Tags: r

I am working with two sets of token-dataframes which have unequal number of rows. I want to create a list of sentences from this table,

```
df1  name               df2   word  
1    john               1     john
2    jesse              2     eats 
3    jonathan           3     chocolate     
                        4     jesse
                        5     loves
                        6     football  
                        7     jonathan   
                        8     wants
                        9     another
                        10    beer
```

I want the output to be in a list. e.g:

```
list()
[[1]]
john
[1]
john eats chocolate
```

I have tried a for loop but it turns out to be one word per list:

```
final = list()
J = length(df2$word)
K = length(df1$name)

for (i in 1:K){
  for (j in 1:L){
    if (str_detect(df1$name[i], df2$word[j] )== TRUE) {
      final[j] <- df1$name[i]
    } else { paste0(df2$word[j], collapse = " ") }
  }
}
```

output:

```
[[1]]
john
[[2]]
eats
[[3]]
chocolate
[[4]]
jesse
[[5]]
loves
[[6]]
football
[[7]]
jonathan
[[8]]
wants
[[9]]
another
[[10]]
beer
```

One of my colleagues tells me that it needs to be in a while loop. Hope someone can help explain what the problem is. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Your expected output is just `as.list(df2$word)`. I don't see how `df1` comes into play.

Comment: I guess he wants three elements in the list: one is called `John` with the first 3 words, a second one called `Jesse` with the next four ones and the last one called `Jonathan` with the last 4 words. Is that, @Alang Alang?

Comment: This is less efficient but maybe it might help `apply(df2,2,function(x) split(x,ceiling(seq_along(x)/3)))[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes you can just leave everything in separate lists. We don't gain anything by having them in dataframes for this execercise because they are all the same class of object.

It appears that you want to make sentences by iterating through multiple lists of words. I've taken the liberty to rearrange your word lists into different categories (names/nouns, verbs, and direct objects) so that each iteration will make a complete sentence. The code below will produce a list of where each element is a string of characters (sentence) with the name in the sentence as the name of the list element.

Cheers,

```
list_name = c("john", "jesse", "jonathon")
list_verb = c("likes", "loves", 'plays', "wants")
list_direct_object = c("football", "another beer", "chocolate")

final = list()

n = 1
for (i in 1:length(list_name)){
  for (j in 1:length(list_verb)){
    for(k in 1:length(list_direct_object)){
      final[[n]] = paste(list_name[i], list_verb[j], list_direct_object[k])
      names(final[[n]]) <- list_name[i]
     n=n+1
    }
  }
}
```

Here is are the first four elements in the list (of 36 total):

```
# [[1]]
# john 
# "john likes football" 
# 
# [[2]]
# john 
# "john likes another beer" 
# 
# [[3]]
# john 
# "john likes chocolate" 
# 
# [[4]]
# john 
# "john loves football"
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will be better if you can process your data better or store in better format. Depending on my understanding of your problem, I think this is what you're looking for. But this is too specific for this problem.

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("john", "jesse", "jonathan"), stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(word = c("john", "eats", "chocolates", "jesse", "loves",
                           "football", "jonathan", "wants", "another", "beer"), stringsAsFactors = F)
K = length(df1$name)
L = length(df2$word)

# get name = word indices
df2_index = c()
for (i in 1:K){
  for (j in 1:L){
    if (identical(df1$name[i], df2$word[j] )) {
      df2_index <- c(df2_index, j) # get indices of the similar names from 'word'
    } 
  }
} 

# paste sentences
final <- list()
for(i in 1:length(df2_index)-1){
  final[i] <- paste(df2$word[(df2_index[i]) : (df2_index[i+1] - 1)], collapse = " ")
}
final[i] <- paste(df2$word[df2_index[i]:(length(df2$word))] , collapse = " ") # only for last 'name'
names(final) <- df1$name # renaming list names
```

Output:

```
> final
$john
[1] "john eats chocolates"

$jesse
[1] "jesse loves football"

$jonathan
[1] "jonathan wants another beer"
```